# supervisor:start_child vs rest_for_one

Tags: erlang, erlang-supervisor

If a supervisor uses the `rest_for_one` restart strategy, and a child is added to it using `supervisor:start_child`, is the new child considered to be "before" or "after" the existing children?

Or put in another way, if the existing child is `A` and the new child is `B`, would `B` die if `A` died, or would `A` die if `B` died?  I presume the former, but the documentation doesn't explicitly state it.

Answer (score 1):

From [Erlang Documentation](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/supervisor.html)

```
rest_for_one - if one child process terminates and should be 
 restarted, the 'rest' of the child processes -- i.e. the child processes after 
 the terminated child process in the start order -- are terminated. Then the 
 terminated child process and all child processes after it are restarted.
```

So if you add a child, it will be restarted if any existing child dies but the new child cannot kill any other existing child, the order here is the **start order.**